# Deleting S3 files using AWS data pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to delete all S3 keys starting with some prefix using AWS data Pipeline.
I am using AWS Shell Activity for this.

These are the argument

```
  "scriptUri": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_s3_bucket/hive/removeExitingS3.sh",
  "scriptArgument": "s3://my_s3_bucket/output/2017-03-19",
```

I want to delete all S3 keys starting with 2017-03-19 in output folder. What should be command to do this?

I have tried this command in `.sh` file

```
  sudo yum -y upgrade aws-cli 
  aws s3 rm $1 --recursive
```

This is not working.

Sample files are

```
s3://my_s3_bucket/output/2017-03-19/1.txt
s3://my_s3_bucket/output/2017-03-19/2.txt
s3://my_s3_bucket/output/2017-03-19_3.txt
```

**EDIT:**

The date(2017-03-19) is dynamic and this is output of #`{format(@scheduledStartTime,"YYYY-MM-dd")}`. So effectively

```
 "scriptArgument": "s3://my_s3_bucket/output/{format(@scheduledStartTime,"YYYY-MM-dd")}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
aws s3 rm $1 --recursive --exclude "*" --include "2017-03-19*" --include "2017-03-19/*"
```

with

```
"scriptArgument": "s3://my_s3_bucket/output/"
```

**EDIT:**
As the date is a dynamic param, pass it as the second `scriptArgument` to the Shell command activity,

```
aws s3 rm $1 --recursive --exclude "*" --include "$2*" --include "$2/*"
```

Comment: Date is dynamic and equal to #{format(@scheduledStartTime,"YYYY-MM-dd")}

Comment: Pass it as an additional `scriptArgument` and refer it as `$2` inside the script.

Comment: So, It would become aws s3 rm $1 --recursive --exclude "*" --include "$2*" or aws s3 rm $1 --recursive --exclude "*" --include $2*

Comment: `aws s3 rm $1 --recursive --exclude "*" --include "$2*"`

Comment: I am not able to delete s3://my_s3_bucket/output/2017-03-19/1.txt and s3://my_s3_bucket/output/2017-03-19/2.txt using this command I am able to delete s3://my_s3_bucket/output/2017-03-19_3.txt

Comment: sorry, did not notice the `/` in it. Try `aws s3 rm $1 --recursive --exclude "*" --include "$2*" --include "$2/*"`. If there is `/` in the key, it must be handled separately.

Comment: This did solve the problem. Thanks :) You can update the answer.